# Getting enum descriptions from a class in webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, enums, drop-down-menu

I am new to C# and i have question,

I have a web service(webservice1) which has a class in it.. the class has an enum..

```
public class testnum
{
     public enum test
     {
        [Description("1,2,3")]
        123,
        [Description("3,4,5")]
        345,
        [Description("6,7,8 ")]
        678,
     }
}
```

i am trying to create a client to the web service and want to bind the enum descriptions to a dropdown list and the enum values to their respective list items... I  was trying some thing like

```
   protected void ddl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webservice1.Service s = new webservice1.Service();

    foreach( webservice1.test value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(webservice1.test)))
  {
      ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem(value.GetEnumDescription(), value.ToString()));

  }
        }

         }
               public static class ENUMHelper
         {
          public static string GetEnumDescription(this Enum value)
         {
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
        (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
        false);

    if (attributes != null &&
        attributes.Length > 0)
        return attributes[0].Description;
    else
        return value.ToString();         
}
```

}

when I do this it dosent get the descriptions into the drop downlist.. rather it gets the value..

can someone let me know where ia m going wrong??

I even looked at [.NET databinding a combobox to a string enum with Description attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920767/net-databinding-a-combobox-to-a-string-enum-with-description-attributes) but it dosent work in my case .. can someone please help.

PS: let me know if i am not clear i explain my question again!

Comment: The client will have a service reference that contains the `test` enum type.  Look at that generated .cs code, and see if it has retained the `Description` attributes.  It seems likely to me that it has not.  In this case, you'll need to go about this another way.  One approach would be to try to include the source file describing `test` in the client project, instead of letting it generate a service reference to it.  That way, the `Description` attribute still exists.  Note that this means it'll be hardcoded on the client side, which might not always match the server.

Comment: where can i see the service reference.. i just have the service.disco and service.wsdl :( sorry i am now .. if the question is too silly.. i highly apologize :( can u please let me know?

Comment: In the Solution Explorer window, click the Show All Files button.  You should see a .cs file in that same area.  Or open your ref folder in Windows Explorer and look for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this is to include the source file describing test in the client project, instead of letting it generate a service reference to it as suggested by @tim s in one of his comments!!